# Creating Stored Procedure With Variable Number of Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a SQL Server stored procedure with a varying number of parameters. It is similar to "params" in C#.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them in an XML and try OPENXML feature.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You **cannot**.

What you can do is provide a default value for some of your stored procedure parameters, so you don't have to specify them when calling your stored procedure.

If you're on SQL Server 2008 or up, you could also investigate the [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) (or [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters)) - basically the ability to pass in a table of data to your stored procedure. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: As far as I know table valued parameter also have a specific number of columns which should be passed (the columns that were there when you created the type)?

Comment: So how to implement some function like C# `string.Join` for example? It's just impossible? We can create a table parameter, but wanted syntax is `DELCARE @something varchar(max) = STRING_JOIN(', ', 'a', 'b', 'z');`, like `sp_executesql` does